# Authenticate to KeyVault As Dummy App Service Identity from Localhost

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I have WebApp which I host on Azure App Service. It also uses certain values from KeyVault.

WebApp authenticates to KeyVault using Managed Service Identity of AppService and assigning the identity permissions in keyvault it works.

However, I am yet to figure out, how can I possibly get around this or perform dummy authentication when I am debugging on localhost. because localhost can't directly authenticate to keyvault.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: which nuget package are u using to connec to keyvault ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to debug on the localhost, we could use  [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication) to do that. For more information, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources).

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
```

**Note:**

- If there is no [Azure Services Authentication Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrismann.MicrosoftVisualStudioAsalExtension) installed, you could download and install the extension.
- Give access Keyvault right to your account.
- Login with your account

[image]

Comment: this is interesting answer. I have visual studio 2017 enterprise version 15.7.1 ..  Downloading and installing this extension gives me an error message. No version found supporting this extension.any idea?

Comment: `The Azure Services Authentication extension works on Visual Studio 2017 update 5 (Update 6 includes this functionality in-box).`  It seems that it is included in your VS 15.7.1. There is no need to install it again. You could check it from `Tools->Options->Azure Service Authentication`.