# Fetching access token for keyvault

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have published a web app locally and hooked it up to IIS.

When I try to navigate to the site it fails at startup with the following error when trying to access the *keyvault*:

Application startup exception:

> Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException:
>   Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
>   Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority:
>   https://login.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47.
>   Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access
>   token, but none of them worked. Parameters: Connection String: [No
>   connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net,
>   Authority:
>   https://login.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47.
>   Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity.
>
> Unable to connect to the Managed Service Identity (MSI) endpoint.
>
> Please check that you are running on an Azure resource that has MSI
>   setup.
>
> Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
>   Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority:
>   https://login.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47.
>
> Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio.
>
> Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file
>   not found at
>   "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json"
>
> Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
>   Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority:
>   https://login.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47. config
>   (most recent call last):
>   File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>   File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>   File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qw7dqhq0\azure-cli\azure\cli__main__.py", line 32, in  
>   File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qw7dqhq0\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core__init__.py", line 511, in get_default_cli
>   File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qw7dqhq0\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core__init__.py", line 34, in **init**
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\knack\cli.py",  line 82, in **init**     self.config = config_cls(config_dir=config_dir, config_env_var_prefix=config_env_var_prefix)
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\knack\config.py",
>   line 38, in **init**     ensure_dir(config_dir)
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\sitepackages\knack\util.py", line 38, in ensure_dir     os.makedirs(d)
>   File "os.py", line 220, in makedirs PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.azure'

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem and finally found that I wasn't logged in to Azure locally.

What fixed the issue for me was downloading the Azure CLI to my machine and running

```
az login
```

and just follow the resultant pages to login in. Run your app and you should find it connects now.

Answer (score 8):

If you are attempting to use user based AAD authentication while running full IIS localhost, you must follow these instructions to configure your user profile to run the IIS app pool:

[Can't retrieve tokens when debugging app in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#cant-retrieve-tokens-when-debugging-app-in-iis)

> - Configure the Application Pool for the web app to run as your current user account. See more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#configuring-iis-application-pool-identities)
> - Configure "setProfileEnvironment" to "True". See more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel#configuration).
>
>   - Go to %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
>   - Search for "setProfileEnvironment". If it's set to "False", change it to "True". If it's not present, add it as an attribute to the processModel element (/configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/applicationPoolDefaults/processModel/@setProfileEnvironment), and set it to "True".

Once this is configured, [use the other tips found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507071/343347) to either login to AzCli or VisualStudio App Authentication.

Also FYI - if you have users elevating to admin with a separate user account to run Visual Studio / IIS  -- they must also elevate their command prompt with the same user when authenticating to the CLI

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this document [Managed Service Indentity](https://odetocode.com/blogs/all?page=3), the managed service identity only works inside the Azure environment, and only in the App Service deployment in which you configured it.

**Note**: the MSI does **not work with** App Service deployment **slot** at this time.

Before coding, we need to [setup](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-managed-service-identity) something in Azure:

1.Enable Managed Service Identity on the Web App

2.Allow the generated Service Principal access to the Production Key Vault

Here is my code to get token and it works well:

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string token = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net");
```

For more details about how to get Azure KeyVault with MSI in Asp.net Core, you could refer to this [article](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-azure-keyvault-msi).

Comment: But when I run the site via Visual Studio it works fine. It's just that when I publish it to a folder and then hook the folder up to IIS and then hit it from the browser I get this error. So, why is it that it works with Visual studio and not when IIS is involved ?
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @user3911247, in visual studio you may install `Azure Services Authentication Extension` which could retrieve your account info. When you give the access to key vault for your account, then you could successfully get access token. While IIS do not have the extension. For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878643/authenticate-to-keyvault-as-dummy-app-service-identity-from-localhost/50924516#50924516) and this [article](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrismann.MicrosoftVisualStudioAsalExtension).