# Unable to call smulate an Function from post Man to update a database

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, postman

I have  an Azure function that  get an HTTP request , this azure function call a Stored Procedure  who update the database,
The Stored Procedure  works well and update the table in DB.
But when i ant to simulate this request with postMan i had error(`500 :Internal Serveur Erro`).

Here is my Function Azure:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using Core.Handlers;
using System.Text.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

     namespace RealTimeTriggerFunctions
    {
  public static class SendToAzureSql
 {    
      private static readonly string AZURE_TABLE1= 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TABLE1"); 

    // Handler
    private static AzureSqlHandler azSqlHandler;

    [FunctionName("SendToAzureSql")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string procedureName = "";
        try
        {
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
            {
                return new BadRequestResult();
            }
            dynamic message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            if (message == null)
            {
                return new BadRequestResult();
            }
            log.LogInformation((string)message.type.ToString()+ " progress...");
            switch (message.type.ToString())
            {                   
                case "xx.yy.zz.event.table1.table1":
                    procedureName = "stored_table1";
                    InitHandlers(log, AZURE_TABLE1);
                    break;
                default:
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Wrong Request!");
            }

            var dataJson = JsonDocument.Parse(requestBody);
            string actionType = message.type.ToString().Contains("deleted") ? "Deleted": "Default";
            await azSqlHandler.UpsertItemAsync(procedureName, actionType, payload: 
         dataJson.RootElement);
            return new OkObjectResult(message.type.ToString() + " Processed");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.LogError($"An error occurred while processing request : '{e.Message}'");
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Init connexions
    /// </summary>
    private static void InitHandlers(ILogger log, string connectionString)
    {
        // Create handler
        azSqlHandler = new AzureSqlHandler(log, connectionString);
    }
}
```

}

I call this request in POST : `http://localhost:7071/API/SendToAzureSql` I get `500`.

Comment: what's the error? "i had some error" is not enough info.

Comment: @Kashyap, yes i mentionned in the end .. i run it in my local   then i got  500 :Internal Serveur Error

Comment: If you're running this locally you should be able to see the full Exception stack trace in logs. If you're running this in cloud then goto portal->Function-App->Functions-><your-function>->Monitor and click on the failed execution to see logs. To debug I recommend that you put all of your Function's implementation inside a try-catch-all block and log it.

Comment: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Unable to connect to the Instance Metadata Service (IMDS). Skipping request to the Managed Service Identity (MSI) token endpoint. i get that

Comment: Great! Fix that.

Comment: But how! they told me that tehre is a missiong token , i thins it 's my cnnx with the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here:
[Fetching access token for keyvault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52965691/fetching-access-token-for-keyvault)
i run az- login in my Azure cli and it Works